Trouble copying file during docker build
I'm trying to build a CI/CD pipeline using Gitlab. The application depends on a certificate that exists locally but is not committed. When building from a pipeline, the file is passed into docker using Gitlab Variables, but the file can't be found at runtime causing the application to crash. Any help would be appreciated. If you build and deploy the application locally we don't get any issues.
`
Gitlab-ci.yml
image: docker:latest
services:
   - name: docker:dind

default:
  tags:
    - docker
    
before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache curl python3 py3-pip
  - apk add --no-cache aws-cli
  - aws --version
  - docker -v
stages:
  - build

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  CA_CERT: ${CERT}

build_staging:
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - mkdir -p /app/res/database
    - echo "${CA_CERT}" > /app/res/database/ca-central-1-bundle.pem
    - ls -al /app/res/database
    - docker login -u AWS -p $(aws ecr get-login-password --region {region} ${ECR_REGISTRY}
    - docker build -f Dockerfile --platform linux/amd64 --build-arg=CA_CERT_CONTENT=${CA_CERT} -t ${IMAGE_NAME} .
    - docker tag {image-name}:latest {registry}
    - docker push {registry}
    - aws apprunner start-deployment --service-arn {arn} --region {region}

Dockerfile
# Base image
FROM node:14

ARG CA_CERT_CONTENT
ENV CA_CERT_CONTENT=${CA_CERT_CONTENT}

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy project files
COPY . .

# Create the necessary directory structure for the certificate
RUN mkdir -p /app/res/database

# Create the certificate file from the build argument
RUN echo "${CA_CERT_CONTENT}" > /app/res/database/ca-central-1-bundle.pem

# Install node modules
RUN npm install

# Build the app
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8081

# Start the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

I've tried a few different methods of copying the certificate and my ls shows the certificate is present during my runners build step. So I must be copying the file into my container wrong.
This is my runtime error when starting the application:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'app/res/database/ca-central-1-bundle.pem'
